# Power Automate: Sharepoint List Export to Sql Server

Tags: list, sharepoint, power-automate

I need to do a one time load of all the rows from a Sharepoint list into Sql Server.  I am having trouble with parsing through the Get Items control.  Especially for fields that are arrays.
Has anybody tried this before?

Thanks

Barry

Comment: You need to provide more information, "I am having trouble with ..." doesn't really help us help you.  Can you provide some screenshots?  Errors?

Comment: Not sure what's your main issue, if possible, please provide detailed steps or screenshot, here is an article about arrays or collections in Power Automate for your reference:https://sharepains.com/2018/07/10/power-automate-shed-some-light-on-arrays/